# How competitive will my profile be for Grad School

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gre

I'm new to this site and this will be my first question. I am currently a Sophomore at Northern Kentucky University, I'm holding a 3.92 GPA (with no intention of it lowering,) I won the undergraduate research award this year at the University and in the process of getting one of my research papers published (History Major.) Prior to attending NKU, I was active duty Coast Guard for six years. I believe my time in the Coast Guard will help "round out" my academic profile (and can be spun as such). Given my GPA, which will hold above 3.9, my background, and published research papers (assuming I publish two for the sake of this question,) recieve good LOR's mixed with a solid SOP, what History Graduate Program rank/range should I apply for? Also for the sake of this post let's assume my GRE scores match my practice/simulation score of (V 163, Q 157 AWA 5.5)

I know this can be difficult to answer as numerous factors play into this. I'm not attempting to know if I can get into a specific University, but rather should I be applying for a top 100 Grad Pro., Top 50, Top 25 etc. Any advice or recommendations would be truly helpful. Also I can retake the GRE multiple times if any one has a target score for me.

Very Respectfully

Comment: This isn't a very good question for this site as (a) it is too personal and (b) the answers will be mostly opinion based. Only an admissions office will evaluate your cv. Your professors might be able to give you some better advice based on their experience with past students at your school. See the help center for more on questions and such: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: You should consider reading “The Professor is In” to get a realistic idea of what grad school is like in the Humanities.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question should be reconsidered:
1. What specific area of history do you want to study?
2. What do you want to do with your grad degree?
Based on those two questions you could then consider what program is a best fit and be somewhat less concerned with whether it is a top 25 vs. top 50 vs. top 100 program.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hey Key99, I intend to focus on SE Asian History. Ultimately a PhD would be necessary, as I plan on becoming a a History Professor.